# Regex capitalize first letter every word, also after a special character like a dash

Tags: regex, letter, capitalize

I use this to capitalize every first letter every word:

```
#(\s|^)([a-z0-9-_]+)#i
```

I want it also to capitalize the letter if it's after a special mark like a dash (-).

Now it shows:

> This Is A Test For-stackoverflow

And I want this:

> This Is A Test For-Stackoverflow

Comment: Do you also need to capitalize non-ASCII letters (`à`, `ü` etc.)? What language are you using?

Comment: What language's regex are you asking about?

Answer (score 36):

+1 for word boundaries, and here is a comparable Javascript solution. This accounts for possessives, as well:

```
var re = /(\b[a-z](?!\s))/g;
var s = "fort collins, croton-on-hudson, harper's ferry, coeur d'alene, o'fallon"; 
s = s.replace(re, function(x){return x.toUpperCase();});
console.log(s); // "Fort Collins, Croton-On-Hudson, Harper's Ferry, Coeur D'Alene, O'Fallon"
```

Comment: toUpperCase is capitalizing the whole word. Here is the solution:
s.replace(re, function(x){return x.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + x.slice(1);});

Comment: @Polopollo, in this case the regex is only returning one letter if it matches but globally. So there is no need for that extra coding and it should work as is.

Comment: This will not work as OP has asked since a single character would not get capitalized. Just for anybody who comes to this question like I did.

Comment: I fear this doesn't work:
word boundaries include things like '. So `don't` becomes `Don'T`

Comment: @Anderas that's what the negative lookahead is for: `(?!\s)` checks if it's not a character before whitespace. On the other hand, this fails when a word like `don't` is followed by a non-whitespace, non-alphanumeric character like a comma, period or exclamation mark. It would be better to use a word boundary in the lookahead: `/(\b[a-z](?!\b))/g;`

Comment: @GuidoBouman: Your suggested regex fails for Coeur D'Alene and O'Fallon though.

Answer (score 20):

A simple solution is to use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
#\b[a-z0-9-_]+#i
```

Alternatively, you can match for just a few characters:

```
#([\s\-_]|^)([a-z0-9-_]+)#i
```

Comment: @Tim - I took artistic freedom and didn't change the way the OP matches letters - It's *possible* Simmer wants the letter as output, change their colors or whatnot. Also, didn't gave it that much thought, I only had 4 minutes `:P`

Comment: Can someone please add jsfiddle example would be helpful

Comment: Which language's regex is this for?

Comment: @JohnK - Both of these are simple enough and should work in all languages. `#` is a separator here, so your language may need `"\\b[a-z0-9-_]+"` and an `IgnoreCase` flag.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to use **pure regular expressions** you must use the **`\u`**.

To transform this string:

**This Is A Test For-stackoverflow**

into

**This Is A Test For-Stackoverflow**

You must put:
**`(.+)-(.+)`** to capture the values before and after the "-"
then to replace it you must put:

**`$1-\u$2`**

If it is in bash you must put:

`echo "This Is A Test For-stackoverflow" | sed 's/\(.\)-\(.\)/\1-\u\2/'`

Comment: This works amazingly, thank you. However, could you please link so documentation as to how \u flag actually works and how does it capitalize the first letter of the second group?

Comment: @Harshal, I don't understand your question, but I'll try to answer. With the "\u" flag you are saying that you want to capitalize the first character of the string that follows. if you use the expression (.+)-(.+) the value $2 is what corresponds to what is inside the second parenthesis, that's why "u\$2" is capitalizing the first letter, in this example it is "S" by stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you, to be more precise, I was curious about any documentation which says, "\u" does the capitalisation of first letter. It works as expected, I just wanted to read more about this flag.

Answer (score 8):

Actually dont need to match full string just match the first non-uppercase letter like this:

```
'~\b([a-z])~'
```

Comment: in js, i've added `g` like `/\b([a-z])/g` to capitalize each word

Comment: i like your lovely answer @StalinGino must say this is the only one i was able to understand.

Comment: That is as per the requirements. Check all other answers as well.

Answer (score 4):

For JavaScript, here’s a solution that works across different languages and alphabets:

```
const originalString = "this is a test for-stackoverflow"
const processedString = originalString.replace(/(?:^|\s|[-"'([{])+\S/g, (c) => c.toUpperCase())
```

It matches any non-whitespace character `\S` that is preceded by a the start of the string `^`, whitespace `\s`, or any of the characters `-"'([{`, and replaces it with its uppercase variant.

Answer (score 3):

my solution using javascript

```
function capitalize(str) {
  var reg = /\b([a-zÁ-ú]{3,})/g;
  return string.replace(reg, (w) => w.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1));
}
```

with es6 + javascript

```
const capitalize = str => 
    str.replace(/\b([a-zÁ-ú]{3,})/g, (w) => w.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1));



/<expression-here>/g
```

1. `[a-zÁ-ú]` here I consider all the letters of the alphabet, including capital letters and with accentuation.
   ex: **sábado de** J**aneiro às** 19**h**. **sexta**-**feira** **de janeiro às** 21 **e horas**
2. `[a-zÁ-ú]{3,}` so I'm going to remove some letters that are not big enough
   ex: **sábado** de J**aneiro** às 19h. **sexta**-**feira** de **janeiro** às 21 e **horas**
3. `\b([a-zÁ-ú]{3,})` lastly i keep only words that complete which are selected. Have to use () to isolate the last expression to work.
   ex: **sábado** de Janeiro às 19h. **sexta**-**feira** de **janeiro** às 21 e **horas**

after achieving this, I apply the changes only to the words that are in lower case

```
string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1); // output -> Output
```

joining the two

```
str.replace(/\b(([a-zÁ-ú]){3,})/g, (w) => w.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1));
```

result:
**Sábado** de Janeiro às 19h. **Sexta**-**Feira** de **Janeiro** às 21 e **Horas**

Answer (score 1):

Python solution:

```
>>> import re
>>> the_string = 'this is a test for stack-overflow'
>>> re.sub(r'(((?<=\s)|^|-)[a-z])', lambda x: x.group().upper(), the_string)
'This Is A Test For Stack-Overflow'
```

read about the "[positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)"

Answer (score 1):

While this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65344691/1952287) for a pure *Regular Expression solution* is accurate:

```
echo "This Is A Test For-stackoverflow" | sed 's/\(.\)-\(.\)/\1-\u\2/'
```

it should be noted when using any **Case-Change Operators**:

```
\l            Change case of only the first character to the right lower case. (Note: lowercase 'L')
\L            Change case of all text to the right to lowercase.
\u            Change case of only the first character to the right to uppercase.
\U            Change case of all text to the right to uppercase.
```

the end delimiter should be used:

```
\E
```

so the end result should be:

```
echo "This Is A Test For-stackoverflow" | sed 's/\(.\)-\(.\)/\1-\u\E\2/'
```

Answer (score -1):

this will make

*R.E.A.C De Boeremeakers*

from

*r.e.a.c de boeremeakers*

```
(?<=\A|[ .])(?<up>[a-z])(?=[a-z. ])
```

using

```
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(inputText, "(?<=\A|[ .])(?<up>[a-z])(?=[a-z. ])")
    Dim outputText As New StringBuilder
    If matches(0).Index > 0 Then outputText.Append(inputText.Substring(0, matches(0).Index))
    index = matches(0).Index + matches(0).Length
    For Each Match As Match In matches
        Try
            outputText.Append(UCase(Match.Value))
            outputText.Append(inputText.Substring(Match.Index + 1, Match.NextMatch.Index - Match.Index - 1))
        Catch ex As Exception
            outputText.Append(inputText.Substring(Match.Index + 1, inputText.Length - Match.Index - 1))
        End Try
    Next
```