# How to do Initial Caps With Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Dynamic Breadcrumb set up with JavaScript. All I want is to do Initial Caps for each word.

Example:
Home > Some > Page

Currently I have them all converted to lowercase and have removed all - from the strings in pages that have multiple words. I just need to convert the string to Initial Caps. Here is my code that I have working so far:

```
var path = "",
    href = document.location.href,
    domain =  href.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1],
    replacedomain = 'http://' + domain + '/',
    s = href.replace(/-/gi, " ").split("/"),
    lastElement = document.location.href.split('/').splice(-1,1);



for (var i = 2; i < (s.length - 1); i++) {
    path += "<a class='bc' href=\"" + href.substring(0, href.indexOf("/" + s[i]) + s[i].length + 1) + "/\">" + s[i] + "</a> >  ";

    if (i > 0) { 
       breadcrumb = path;  
    }
}


i = s.length - 1;
breadcrumb += "<span>" + s[i] + "</span>";


var breadcrumbl = breadcrumb.toLowerCase(),
    domain =  breadcrumbl.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1],
    breadcrumb2 = breadcrumbl.replace(domain, "").replace(domain, ""),
    breadcrumbs = breadcrumb2,
    url = '<a href="/">Home</a>' + breadcrumbs;

document.getElementById('breadcrumb1').innerHTML=url;
```

I think the solution is with a regular expression but I'm not good at writing them and I'm having a hard time with the concept. Also if anyone thinks this script can be optimized further your feedback is welcome. I'll will make variable names more semantic for production.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use css:

```
span.breadcrump {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I recently wrote this helper method to do this for me:

```
function autocase ( text ) {
    return text.replace(/(&)?([a-z])([a-z]{2,})(;)?/ig,function ( all, prefix, letter, word, suffix ) {
        if (prefix && suffix) {
            return all;
        }

        return letter.toUpperCase() + word.toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

It takes into account things such as `&trade;`

Edit: To use this method, simply pass it a string, and it will return the string auto cased. It does not work on html strings.

```
//...
document.getElementById('breadcrumb1').innerHTML=url;
function autocase ( text ) {
    return text.replace(/(&)?([a-z])([a-z]{2,})(;)?/ig,function ( all, prefix, letter, word, suffix ) {
        if (prefix && suffix) {
            return all;
        }

        return letter.toUpperCase() + word.toLowerCase();
    });
}
$("#breadcrumb1 a").text(function(i,text){
    return autoCase(text);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using css property `text-transform:capitalize;` for the breadcrumb.

Mostlikely in you case it should be,

```
.breadcrumb1 a {
   text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Comment: I only want the first letter capitalized not the entire word. Initial Caps

Comment: @ddilsaver that's exactly what the answer does. `capitalize` capitalizes words. `uppercase` converts all letters to uppercase.

Comment: My mistake I was thinking of **text-transform: uppercase** your correct

Comment: Keep in mind that `text-transformation` doesn't really change the value casing (to upper or whatever case), it's only for visual representation, so if you need to submit that value to the server, it will be on its original form. I would do what Kevin B did.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought is:

```
breadcrumb += "<span>" + s[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + s[i].substring(1) + "</span>";
```

But [@Esailija's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10094706/82548) is much easier.
Reference:

- [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase).

Comment: I upvoted this one because I needed a JS solution, not css. I want to capitalize words that have at least 3 characters, but shorter words are probably abbreviations and need to be all-caps. I don't think there is a simpler solution for this in CSS.

Answer (score 3):

not to be a punk but why not just use css?

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

Comment: I only want the first letter capitalized not the entire word. Initial Caps

Comment: @ddilsaver that's exactly what the answer does. `capitalize` capitalizes words. `uppercase` converts all letters to uppercase.

Comment: My mistake I was thinking of text-transform: uppercase your correct

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if you really need JS but in CSS you can easily use text-transform:Capitalize;

Answer (score 2):

Since the accepted answer didn't actually answer the question as it was asked, I figured this might help; it's a solution using Regex with JavaScript, originally found here: [Regex capitalize first letter every word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251463/regex-capitalize-first-letter-every-word-also-after-a-special-character-like-a)

Here's the snippet I found useful:

```
var re = /(\b[a-z](?!\s))/g;
var s = "fort collins, croton-on-hudson, harper's ferry, coeur d'alene, o'fallon"; 
s = s.replace(re, function(x){return x.toUpperCase();});
console.log(s); // "Fort Collins, Croton-On-Hudson, Harper's Ferry, Coeur D'Alene, O'Fallon"
```

Comment: May want to add s = s.toLowerCase() somewhere before the replace, just to make sure the rest of it is indeed lowercase. Well.. if you're dealing with randomly cased input. But overall I like this solution.  Css does not actually change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one:

```
s.replace(/(^[a-zA-Z]{1})/,function (s){
  return s.toUpperCase();
});
```