# capitalize every letter after dash or space (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to capitalize every letter after space and dash.
Obviously, capitalizing every letter after a space isn't a problem:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z-\s]/s', '', $string);
$string = ucwords(strtolower($string));
```

does the trick.

However, I can't find a way to capitalize every letter after a dash, although [this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251463/regex-capitalize-first-letter-every-word-also-after-a-special-character-like-a) seems to match every letter after a dash (if i trust the answer).

Any help is appreciated!

I also tried:

```
$string = preg_replace('#\b[a-z0-9-_]+#i', strtoupper("$0"), $string);
```

without success...

Comment: I've made a javascript version once upon a time :) hope it helps: `str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/^(.)|\s(.)|\#(.)/g, function (letter) {
 return letter.toUpperCase();
});`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
preg_replace_callback('/(?<=( |-))./',
                      function ($m) { return strtoupper($m[0]); },
                      $string);
```

`/(?<=( |-))./` is *"any character (`.`) [preceded by (`(?<=)`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) a space or dash (`( |-)`)"*.