# Sublime Text: Regex to convert Uppercase to Title Case?

Tags: regex, string, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have a bunch of labels in a text file (e.g. MY LABEL:) that I need to make title case.

I already know how I would make them all lower or upper case.

For example:

`^([A-Z &#]+:)` to `\L$1`

However, is there a simple switch-based way to get title case?

Comment: This might help. It covers capializing the first letter of every word http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251463/regex-capitalize-first-letter-every-word-also-after-a-special-character-like-a

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Find: `([A-Z])([A-Z]+)\b`

Replace: `$1\L$2`

Make sure case sensitivity is on (Alt + C) and preserve case is off (Alt + A).

Comment: This worked great, but in RegExBuddy it's `\l` (lowercase L) for whatever reason, if this helps anyone.

Comment: `\L` turns all following characters into lowercase, `\l` only the first following character

Comment: Or find `(\w)(\w+)` and replace with `\U$1\L$2` covers all cases, even if words don't start off uppercased.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but this answer did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1159389/672989

Comment: Also, if you want to convert the whole group to uppercase, use `\U$1\E`

Comment: If you want to capitalize: `([a-z])([a-z]+)\b` and then `\u$1$2`

Comment: \U and \L replace the entire following text, while \u and \l only replace the first following character.

Comment: The link is broken. When referring to a page off of StackOverflow, it's important to copy and paste the relevent information into your answer so _when_ the link breaks there's some useful information remaining.

Answer (score 25):

Have you tried the Sublime Text built in? `Edit -> Convert Case -> Title Case.`

[image: Edit -> Convert Case -> Title Case]

Comment: Yes, but I was looking for a way to do it with find/replace.  I'm sorry, I should have been clearer.

Comment: I'd like to note that the built in gives unexpected results (Build 3059). I tested a list of names and email address in the format `first last <email@example.com>,\nfirst last...` and besides the first line, all the first names were left lowercase.

Comment: I really like "Smarter Title Case." You can install it through Package Control. I've noticed that it has a few of it's own flaws, but it's 1000 times better than the built in converter.

Comment: This is perfect. I've been looking for that for a long time.

Comment: @Steve I'm only 11 years later, but hopefully, I can help others. Simply use the CTRL+F and "Find all" such that you've "selected" everything you want to convert to lowercase. Then use the built-in thing as shown in the answer. It's one extra step.