# c# trying to change first letter to uppercase but doesn't work

Tags: c#, regex, uppercase

I have to convert the first letter of every word the user inputs into uppercase. I don't think I'm doing it right so it doesn't work but I'm not sure where has gone wrong D: Thank you in advance for your help! ^^

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter anything: ");
        string x = Console.ReadLine();

        string pattern = "^";
        Regex expression = new Regex(pattern);
        var regexp = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);

        Match result = expression.Match(x);
        Console.WriteLine(x);

        foreach(var match in x)
        {
            Console.Write(match);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: can you add some input and expected output?

Comment: Are you obliged to use `Regex`?

Comment: @sybren yup! i have to use Regex D:

Comment: @vks for example if i type "hello i am sam" it should print out as "Hello I Am Sam"

Comment: @eyeballs here's an example that uses `Regex` : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/regular_case.htm

Answer (score 7):

If your exercise isn't regex operations, there are built-in utilities to do what you are asking:

```
System.Globalization.TextInfo ti = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
string titleString = ti.ToTitleCase("this string will be title cased");

Console.WriteLine(titleString);
```

Prints:

> This String Will Be Title Cased

If you operation *is for regex*, see this previous StackOverflow answer: [Sublime Text: Regex to convert Uppercase to Title Case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835450/sublime-text-regex-to-convert-uppercase-to-title-case)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your Regex "^" matches the start of a line.  If you need to match each word in a multi-word line, you'll need a different Regex, e.g. "[A-Za-z]".

You're also not doing anything to actually change the first letter to upper case.  Note that strings in C# are immutable (they cannot be changed after creation), so you will need to create a new string which consists of the first letter of the original string, upper cased, followed by the rest of the string.  Give that part a try on your own.  If you have trouble, post a new question with your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
string pattern = "(?:^|(?<= ))(.)"
```

`^` doesnt capture anything by itself.You can replace by `uppercase letters` by applying function to `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/29

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this using Model Extensions.

PHP has a nice method called ucfirst.
So I translated that into C#

```
public static string UcFirst(this string s)
{
    var stringArr = s.ToCharArray(0, s.Length);
    var char1ToUpper = char.Parse(stringArr[0]
        .ToString()
        .ToUpper());

    stringArr[0] = char1ToUpper;

    return string.Join("", stringArr);
}
```

Usage:

```
[Test]
public void UcFirst()
{
    string s = "john";
    s = s.UcFirst();
    Assert.AreEqual("John", s);
}
```

Obviously you would still have to split your sentence into a list and call UcFirst for each item in the list.

Google C# Model Extensions if you need help with what is going on.

Comment: Nice, it worked, but had to figure out where to add the method. I created a folder `Extensions` with a class file `String.cs`, added `namespace ProjectName.Extensions { public static class StringExtension { ... } }`, within this class I added the method. To use the extension make sure `using ProjectName.Extensions` is added.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help

```
public static string CapsFirstLetter(string inputValue)
    {
        char[] values = new char[inputValue.Length];
        int count = 0;
        foreach (char f in inputValue){
            if (count == 0){
                values[count] = Convert.ToChar(f.ToString().ToUpper());
            }
            else{
                values[count] = f;
            }
            count++;
        }
        return new string(values);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do it with regex:

```
string input = "this string will be title cased, even if there are.cases.like.that";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!\w)\w", m => m.Value.ToUpper());
```