# Convert UPPERCASE to Title Case

Tags: regex, swift

I want to convert an uppercase string (UPPERCASE) into a title case string (Title Case) in swift. I am not strong in regular expressions, but have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835450/sublime-text-regex-to-convert-uppercase-to-title-case) answer with a regular expression that I have attempted to use.

The search expression is:

```
"([A-Z])([A-Z]+)\b"
```

and the template expression is:

```
"$1\L$2"
```

In order to use it in swift I have escaped the backslashes as seen below:

```
var uppercase = "UPPER CASE STRING"
var titlecase = uppercase.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("([A-Z])([A-Z]+)\\b", withString: "$1\\L$2", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: Range<String.Index>(start: uppercase.startIndex, end: uppercase.endIndex))
```

The code above gives the following result:

```
"ULPPER CLASE SLTRING"
```

From that you can see that the search expression successfully finds the two parts $1 and $2, but it looks like escaping the backslash interferes with the replacement.

How can I get the expected result of:

```
"Upper Case String"
```

Comment: `"$1$L$2"` results in `"U$LPPER C$LASE S$LTRING"`...

Comment: You may want to look into the `NSString` method [`capitalizedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/capitalizedString), which should be available from Swift.

Comment: Judging from "Table 3 – Template Matching Format" in the NSRegularExpression class reference, `\L` is not supported in the replacement template expression.

Comment: @MattGibson: Well that was elegant, you can use it directly with Swift Strings too. Thank you.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks for the prod; done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Many of the useful existing `NSString` methods are available from Swift. This includes [`capitalizedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/capitalizedString), which may just do exactly what you want, depending on your requirements.

Comment: It works for the specific example from the OP, however if you want something a little different, for instance a capital letter after an apostrophe (L'Avion instead of L'avion), then you would need to go for a regex. And I am absolutely missing the \L and/or \U in Swift :/

Answer (score 4):

As I know, title cased string is the string that has the first letter of each word capitalised (except for prepositions, articles and conjunctions). So, the code should be like that:

```
public extension String {
    subscript(range: NSRange) -> Substring {
        get {
            if range.location == NSNotFound {
                return ""
            } else {
                let swiftRange = Range(range, in: self)!
                return self[swiftRange]
            }
        }
    }

    /// Title-cased string is a string that has the first letter of each word capitalised (except for prepositions, articles and conjunctions)
    var localizedTitleCasedString: String {
        var newStr: String = ""

        // create linguistic tagger
        let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: [.lexicalClass], options: 0)
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: self.utf16.count)
        tagger.string = self

        // enumerate linguistic tags in string
        tagger.enumerateTags(in: range, unit: .word, scheme: .lexicalClass, options: []) { tag, tokenRange, _ in
            let word = self[tokenRange]

            guard let tag = tag else {
                newStr.append(contentsOf: word)
                return
            }

            // conjunctions, prepositions and articles should remain lowercased
            if tag == .conjunction || tag == .preposition || tag == .determiner {
                newStr.append(contentsOf: word.localizedLowercase)
            } else {
                // any other words should be capitalized
                newStr.append(contentsOf: word.localizedCapitalized)
            }
        }
        return newStr
    }
}
```