# Capitalize the first letter of each word

Tags: javascript, string

```
var name = "AlbERt EINstEiN";

function nameChanger(oldName) {
var finalName = oldName;
// Your code goes here!
finalName = oldName.toLowerCase();

finalName = finalName.replace(finalName.charAt(0), finalName.charAt(0).toUpperCase());

for(i = 0; i < finalName.length; i++) {
    if (finalName.charAt(i) === " ")
        finalName.replace(finalName.charAt(i+1), finalName.charAt(i+1).toUpperCase());
}


// Don't delete this line!
return finalName;
};

// Did your code work? The line below will tell you!
console.log(nameChanger(name));
```

My code as is, returns 'Albert einstein'. I'm wondering where I've gone wrong?
If I add in

```
console.log(finalName.charAt(i+1));
```

AFTER the if statement, and comment out the rest, it prints 'e', so it recognizes `charAt(i+1)` like it should... I just cannot get it to capitalize that first letter of the 2nd word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your code sample. I'll go through them one-by-one.

**Strings are immutable**

This doesn't work the way you think it does:

```
finalName.replace(finalName.charAt(i+1), finalName.charAt(i+1).toUpperCase());
```

You need to change it to:

```
finalName = finalName.replace(finalName.charAt(i+1), finalName.charAt(i+1).toUpperCase());
```

In JavaScript, strings are **immutable**. This means that once a string is created, it can't be changed. That might sound strange since in your code, it seems like you are changing the string `finalName` throughout the loop with methods like `replace()`.

But in reality, you aren't actually changing it! The `replace()` function takes an input string, does the replacement, and **produces a new output string**, since it isn't actually allowed to change the input string (immutability). So, tl;dr, if you don't capture the output of `replace()` by assigning it to a variable, the replaced string is lost.

Incidentally, it's okay to assign it back to the original variable name, which is why you can do `finalName = finalName.replace(...)`.

---

**Replace is greedy**

The other problem you'll run into is when you use `replace()`, you'll be replacing **all** of the matching characters in the string, not just the ones at the position you are examining. This is because `replace()` is greedy - if you tell it to replace 'e' with 'E', it'll replace all of them!

What you need to do, essentially, is:

1. Find a space character (you've already done this)
2. Grab all of the string up to and including the space; this "side" of the string is good.
3. Convert the very next letter to uppercase, but only that letter.
4. Grab the rest of the string, **past** the letter you converted.
5. Put all three pieces together (beginning of string, capitalized letter, end of string).

The `slice()` method will do what you want:

```
if (finalName.charAt(i) === " ") {
    // Get ONLY the letter after the space
    var startLetter = finalName.slice(i+1, i+2);
    // Concatenate the string up to the letter + the letter uppercased + the rest of the string
    finalName = finalName.slice(0, i+1) + startLetter.toUpperCase() + finalName.slice(i+2);
}
```

---

Another option is regular expression (regex), which the other answers mentioned. This is probably a better option, since it's a lot cleaner. But, if you're learning programming for the first time, it's easier to understand this manual string work by writing the raw loops. Later you can mess with the efficient way to do it.

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9dLw1Lfx/

Further reading:

- [Are JavaScript strings immutable? Do I need a "string builder" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript)
- [slice() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: ... Because? You should at least explain why this change is necessary, especially since this question seems like homework.

Comment: I tried this, and it returns 'AlbErt einstein'. Not really sure why it's grabbing the first 'e', and not the one after the space?

Comment: @xdumaine I agree, I was in the middle of expanding the explanation when you commented :)

Comment: See OP's comment on this answer. The line will replace the first character matching the character at that index. I.e if `finalName.charAt(i+1)` is an `e` then it will replace the first `e` in the string, not necessarily the one at index `i+1`

Comment: Good immutability explanation!

Comment: Worked like that. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I was beginning to question my future as a dev, seeing as I couldn't get some stupid letters to capitalize lol. Thank you again!

Comment: @xdumaine Thanks! Appreciate the feedback and catching my errors. Cheers!

Comment: @MartDellon Absolutely! Happy to help. I could tell you were looking for a basic explanation. We've all struggled with this stuff at one time or another. Keep learning man!

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify this down a lot if you pass a *RegExp* `/pattern/flags` and a *function* into [`str.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) instead of using substrings

```
function nameChanger(oldName) {
    var lowerCase = oldName.toLowerCase(),
        titleCase = lowerCase.replace(/\b./g, function ($0) {return $0.toUpperCase()});
    return titleCase;
};
```

In this example I've applied the change to any character `.` after a [word boundary `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), but you may want the more specific `/(^| )./g`

Comment: This is pretty cryptic, especially to a beginner.

Comment: @xdumaine Which part specifically? I tried to make it clearer by splitting it into three lines. I've edited in some references

Comment: i doubt OP would recognize this replace syntax means that it's using regular expressions, let alone how you came up with those regex or what they mean. That's fairly advanced for a "your code goes here" string manipulation problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another good answer to this question is to use RegEx to do this for you.

```
var re = /(\b[a-z](?!\s))/g;
var s = "fort collins, croton-on-hudson, harper's ferry, coeur d'alene, o'fallon"; 
s = s.replace(re, function(x){return x.toUpperCase();});
console.log(s); // "Fort Collins, Croton-On-Hudson, Harper's Ferry, Coeur D'Alene, O'Fallon"
```

The regular expression being used may need to be changed up slightly, but this should give you an idea of what you can do with regular expressions

[Capitalize Letters with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251463/regex-capitalize-first-letter-every-word-also-after-a-special-character-like-a)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is twofold:

1) You need to return a value for finalName.replace, as the method returns an element but doesn't alter the one on which it's predicated.

2) You're not iterating through the string values, so you're only changing the first word. Don't you want to change every word so it's in lower case capitalized?

This code would serve you better:

```
   var name = "AlbERt EINstEiN";

function nameChanger(oldName) {

    // Your code goes here!

    var finalName = [];
    oldName.toLowerCase().split(" ").forEach(function(word) {
        newWord = word.replace(word.charAt(0), word.charAt(0).toUpperCase());
        finalName.push(newWord);
    });


    // Don't delete this line!
    return finalName.join(" ");
};

    // Did your code work? The line below will tell you!
    console.log(nameChanger(name));
```

Answer (score -4):

```
if (finalName.charAt(i) === " ")
```

Shouldn't it be

```
if (finalName.charAt(i) == " ")
```

Doesn't === check if the object types are equal which should not be since one it a char and the other a string.

Comment: Are you sure that charAt(i) returns a string and not a char?

Comment: This is **not** answering the question in any way. *And* it's wrong, as there's no `char` type in JavaScript, `charAt` just returns a string of length 1.

Comment: CharAt should be a char while " " should be a string. But since it's javascript, don't remember if ' ' == " " due to weak typing.

Comment: @JustinChou _JavaScript_ doesn't have a _Char_ type, it uses _String_ with length `1` (or maybe `2` in some edge cases with an unusual USC-16 character, not sure would need to read spec)